# Is there a way to forward ports through VPN?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

My ISP seems to have filtered all ports. I have found a few decent free VPN services with open ports. Is there a way to forward those open ports to my network address? Or is there any other free VPN services which do this out of the box?

Edit:
I'm trying to establish a meterpreter session with reverse tcp. I have forwarded the required ports on the router and have also added inbound firewall rules. Everything works perfectly fine on LAN. I wanted to see how it works on the WAN but my ISP doesn't seem to have any ports open at all. I want see if port forwarding is possible through free VPN services before changing my ISP.

Comment: Please edit your question to not only include your idea but also your goal because provided what you wrote, we can only guess your goal.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter all ports"? Is your question about VPNs or about being able to run traffic over the filtered ports?

Comment: @UTF-8 I've edited the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @schroeder, I mean to say that all ports are closed.

Comment: I put my answer in before you added your update. It appears then that you want INBOUND access to your local network not that you have having OUTBOUND issues?

Comment: whoa - this is a completely different problem - your ISP isn't allowing inbound connections - VPNs won't help with that

Comment: @JulianKnight limited inbound access is the issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly, it would be helpful if you updated the question again to make that totally clear for future readers.

Comment: Is your server behind a NAT router?  Are you _really really sure_ that is configured right?

Answer (score 4):

There's definitively a way to forward ports with VPN, just not with any VPN service.

You have to rent a server, a cheap VPS box will do, and then set up a VPN between you and it with something like OpenVPN, set up to tunnel your traffic through the server.

Once that is done you can use iptables in the VPS to forward all the ports you want just like you would on a LAN.

Comment: Does forwarding with iptables use the vpn tunnel?

Comment: @Keith VPN will put you in what for all intents and purposes is a LAN with your VPS, and do some routing wizardry to also make the VPS your Internet Gateway. From there you just have to make sure the VPS has NAT set up to share it's Internet connection with the VPN clients (which is also done with iptables) and if necessary set up all your port forwarding needs.

Comment: @Keith I should add that, when I wrote this answer, OpenVPN was the only VPN solution I was familiar with, but the newer versions have backward incompatibilities that may make it's set up significantly more stressful than it used to. I was recommended Tinc VPN as currently being the best solution, and although I haven't tried it yet, I suggest you give it a shot first.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

From your updated question, it is now clear that the issue you have is INBOUND access not outbound. This is a little more normal though even so, they really shouldn't be blocking *everything* unless they've made it clear in your *terms of use* that your connection cannot be used at all for inbound services.

More likely that they are blocking *most* ports which would be more sensible. Have you tried common ports such as 80, 443, 8080 and so on?

A public VPN service is unlikely to help you with this issue as they are also unlikely to allow any inbound access. Though for a different reason. That it is difficult for them to ensure correct routing of traffic and hard to maintain security.

However, if you set up your own VPN, you can certainly then do what you want.

Find a VPS (Virtual Private Server) provider that allows private VPN use (many don't) and set up OpenVPN on there.

---

The open ports on a VPN come from the other end of the connection. E.g. on the network running the VPN service.

The ports that your ISP have open become, therefore, irrelevant other than that you need a single available port to connect to the VPN in the first place.

Your ISP cannot possibly have closed all ports otherwise the connection would be pointless. However, they will have restricted them. As long as you have access to port 443 (the default for HTTPS), there are VPN services you can use.

So you need to check with your VPN supplier what ports *they* have open.

Comment: Most common ports were all open when I last checked about a month ago. But today when I checked, they were all closed. I did a stealth scan of all ports using the cmd: nmap -p- -Pn <ip-address> because ICMP packets were being dropped, and none of the ports seemed to be open. I don't have enough time and resources to spend on VPS or private VPN right now. Moreover, there are a plethora of free VPN service providers out there, there should be some that would allow port forwarding as well, because when you think of it, they just need to forward user specified ports to one's address.

Comment: Inbound is very different for a VPN supplier. Their service is optimised for outbound too. Inbound traffic adds significant risk that has to be protected against, their infrastructure has to be more complex adding to costs in a cut-throat market. Good luck on your search, I've not managed to find a suitable provider with a quick look even for paid services let alone the free ones.

Comment: Also, most if not all public VPN suppliers focus on privacy. An inbound connection would, by definition, ruin that as their systems would have to keep configuration details to enable inbound traffic to reach you.

Comment: I've found one such service called VPNStaticIP. It provides a free trial period of 2 days and has port forwarding enabled. The only caveat is that the connection time is limited to 5 minutes and you have to keep re-connecting, but there are ways around that.

Comment: Good find. Looks like LiquidVPN also offers it as an option on their Pro accounts.

Comment: Thank you. This will do for now. I just wanted to test a few things.